# C# Index out of range on read to string

Tags: c#

I've got an error index out of range Connected (the line highlighted) and I don't know what does mean in this scenario. Can you please give me some advice? Thanks

```
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

while (read.Read())
{
    **String Connessione = (read["Connected"].ToString());**

    if ((Connessione == "Wind Connected") || (Connessione == "Solar Connected"))
    {
        EnerServ.Visible = false;
        AddServ.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {

        EnerServ.Text = (read["Typ"].ToString());
        AddServ.Text = (read["EneServ"].ToString());
    }

}
read.Close();
```

Comment: Show more of your code, including the CommandText.  Most likely, your reader is not returning a column named "Connected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column "Connected" doesn't exist is the returned dataset.

I believe under the hood it's searching for the index of a column called "Connected", which isn't there, so -1 is returned. Then the column with index -1 is located which is out of range, hence the exception.

Comment: I didn't have the connected in my select